# MySql/Wordpress Strip file extensions from certain links

Tags: mysql, wordpress

**A little background.** I've successfully imported 50,000+ posts into wordpress. A lot of the posts have links that reference other pages. Fixing the links could be a matter of a simple search and replace in MySQL, however, the links that exist reference pagetitle.htm, and since the posts they should reference do not have the .htm extension, a 404 is the result.

**EDIT** I mixed things up. Correction below.

> **Old Request:**  I would like to add the .htm to all the links in the database; i.e. add .htm to all links that start with www.example.com/xxxxxx (xxx being the inconsistent). **In MySQL, how do I select all links with a consistent beginning of a string and append .htm, but before the closing  tag?**
>
> i.e.
>
> ```
> change all <a href="website.com/#####">#####</a> *to* <a href="website.com/#####.htm">#####</a>
> ```

**Correction:** *Using mysql, I would like to remove all occurrences of .htm ONLY when link starts with a certain domain.*

I've also tried adding .htm to my permalink structure, but I'm not able apply it to custom post types, only posts and pages. Also, this feels too much like a bandaid. I could be convinced otherwise, however.

Thanks in advance for any help on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this would work in all cases, but here's an idea:

EDITED **
This should do the trick.  Not pretty, but I think it should work.  It looks at everything before the second " mark.  And replaces it with .htm at the end if it is missing it.

```
UPDATE  your_table

SET     post_content = REPLACE(post_content,
                             SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, '"', 2),
                             LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, '"', 2), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, '"', 2)) - 4)
                            )

WHERE   RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, '"', 2),4) = '.htm';
```

ORIGINAL **

```
UPDATE  your_table

SET     link_field = REPLACE(link_field, '"></a>', '.htm"></a>')

WHERE   RIGHT(link_field, 10) <> '.htm"></a>';
```

Comment: Great start. But I should have been more clear. I fixed the example above to reflect the issue. This solution assumes the opening and closing tags aren't divided by anything, when in fact the title of the  post being linked is included.

Comment: Ok.  Take a look now.

Comment: Oops! I totally mixed my request up! I need to REMOVE the .htm from the links, not add. Wow, long day. So, now I need to take every link that starts with <a href="www.site.com/######.htm"></a> and remove the .htm, but ONLY from these sites, so that it doesn't change other links. Really sorry you did that work for nothing! I changed my original question.

Comment: Ok.  I took another shot at it.  Hopefully it does the trick.

Comment: No dice. What should 'your_field' be? I think the issue is that the link exists in the post_content field and is not exclusive. It sits within a lot of other stuff. Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding this.

Comment: So, is this part of a larger string?  If so, could you give an example or two?  Sorry, "your_field" should be "post_content" field I guess.  I'll edit.

Comment: Yes, the links I'm trying to edit are part of larger strings. For instance, an entire news article. "Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum <a href="LINK TO DELETE .htm">lotus</a>.